# Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

This is the project structure.

```
--KP
   --app
       --api
           --views
                --mpg.py
                --gtt.py
```

mpg.py:

```
def cmcid():
     .....
     .....
```

gtt.py:

```
from .mpg import cmcid

def main():
    variable = cmcid()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I run from views directory, i.e kp/app/api/views$python gtt.py

I get an error as:

Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Any help is appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss a `__init__.py` file (it can be just an empty file) in your views directory.

Add this file and it will turn your directory into a python package and the import should work

Note that it is also required in parent directories.

---

Another possible cause is that you use the Django "machinery" in your file, as a consequence it may be not possible to run directly as a python file.

If you need to write python scripts, that interacts with your django app, you need to create a django command that will be executed with `python manage.py got`

Your `gtt.py` file needs to be in `management\commands` submodule of your django app.

It must have the following structure

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from path.to.mpg import cmcid

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Your custom command'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        variable = cmcid()
```

See Django doc for more details about commands
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Yes, I have __init__.py in my views directory

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.5

Comment: There is maybe something wrong in this file that cause the ImportError. If you execute it as main module with python, you will see if the file is correct

Comment: there is no error in that mpg.py
mpg.py uses my models and serializers. Does that cause an error?